# How to properly call Windows API methods from Assembly

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, dll

to put this in simple terms, I am trying to do some assembly by hand (please don't even ask about it)

However, I have come across the problem of calling API functions, like from the win32 API.
In various assembly languages, what you would do is include or import something like "windows.lib" or "windows.inc" or similar.
The problem is, this varies from assembler to assembler and even the output (binary) looks different; I can't figure it out.

So my general question is: How does calling an API method from a DLL library look like in the binary version as in a Windows PE file?

I tried looking around on the Internet to find resources about this, but was unsuccessful...

Answer (score -4):

The best way is to read the microsoft documentation on NTDLL but it is apparently possible to read any reference only by paying (using [the MSDN service](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/msdn-platforms/))

An alternative is:
With a debugger, learning how NTDLL is requested.

Step per Step and more information:

1. First, use a debugger and download several programs and find out what calls they make to NTDLL, what is the abstraction layer for kenel calls, NTDLL is never at the same address, for security reasons, so there can only be one variable that always points to ntdll, that is, a variable register in the ram.
2. Find out what decision mechanism NTDLL uses to define arguments and what the call is for.

References where you can find information about: [Fasm Forum](https://board.flatassembler.net/)  [Article: How call NTDLL directly](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/calling-ntdll-functions-directly/#gref)